# Android Textview stuck on scroll position - auto scrolling it to top

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, scrollview

I'm trying to build a trivia app but facing some problems with textview. The issue is that when I use long question text, the view is stuck on the position where the user stopped scrolling previously. I want it to display the top part(auto scroll to the top) when a question is loaded. Was facing the same issue with the initial question but fixed it by changing

`<LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">`

to

`<LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="top|center" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">`

But I'm unable to achieve the same result when the second question (and questions after that) is loaded. Now the user should manually scroll to the top to read the question which isn't ideal. By changing some values in the xml, is it possible for the textview to display the top portion when new questions are loaded?

Complete xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/play_layout" android:background="@drawable/background" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/relativeLayout" android:background="@color/colorPrimary" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <ImageView android:id="@id/back" android:padding="5.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />
        <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/white" android:id="@id/tvLevel" android:padding="5.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Select Level" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/back" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/white" android:id="@id/txt_question" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip" android:text="1/6" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/setting" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        <ImageView android:id="@id/setting" android:padding="5.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip" android:src="@drawable/settings" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/wave_layout" android:background="@color/colorPrimary" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <View android:id="@id/divider" android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="6.0dip" />
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/score_layout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10.0dip" android:weightSum="3.0" android:layout_below="@id/top_panel">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0">
                    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView android:id="@id/right" android:padding="3.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/check_mark" />
                        <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" android:textColor="@color/white" android:id="@id/txtTrueQuestion" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip" android:text="0" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/right" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView android:id="@id/wrong" android:padding="3.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/cancel_mark" />
                        <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" android:textColor="@color/white" android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/txtFalseQuestion" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip" android:text="0" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/wrong" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <RelativeLayout android:gravity="center" android:padding="5.0dip" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0">
                    <com.quiz.trivia.helper.CircularProgressIndicator android:id="@id/progressBarTwo" android:layout_width="@dimen/progress_h_w" android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_h_w" app:direction="counterclockwise" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0">
                    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="2.0">
                        <ImageView android:id="@id/imgCoin" android:padding="3.0dip" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/coins" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
                        <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" android:textColor="@color/white" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/coin_count" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip" android:text="00" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="2.0">
                        <ImageView android:id="@id/imgScore" android:padding="3.0dip" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/score" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
                        <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" android:textColor="@color/white" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/txtScore" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip" android:text="00" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgScore" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/wave" android:background="@drawable/wave_background" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/wave_layout" />
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/main_layout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@id/bottom_panel" android:layout_below="@id/wave">
            <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/layout_answare" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:id="@id/txtQuestion" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10.0dip" android:text="@string/app_name" android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="100.0">
                        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="85.0">
                            <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/a_layout" android:background="@drawable/answer_bg" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="16.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="8.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="16.0dip">
                                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/main_option_a" android:background="@color/transparent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5.0dip" android:weightSum="5.0" android:layout_centerVertical="true">
                                    <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" android:textColor="@color/white" android:gravity="center|left" android:id="@id/btnOpt1" android:padding="5.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Done" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/b_layout" android:background="@drawable/answer_bg" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="16.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="8.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="16.0dip">
                                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/main_option_b" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5.0dip" android:layout_centerVertical="true">
                                    <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" android:textColor="@color/white" android:gravity="center|left" android:id="@id/btnOpt2" android:padding="5.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Done" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/c_layout" android:background="@drawable/answer_bg" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="16.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="8.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="16.0dip">
                                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/main_option_c" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5.0dip" android:layout_centerVertical="true">
                                    <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" android:textColor="@color/white" android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/btnOpt3" android:padding="5.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Done" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/d_layout" android:background="@drawable/answer_bg" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="16.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="8.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="16.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="8.0dip">
                                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/main_option_d" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5.0dip" android:layout_centerVertical="true">
                                    <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" android:textColor="@color/white" android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/btnOpt4" android:padding="5.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Done" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="4.0" android:layout_weight="15.0">
                            <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/layout_A" android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_progress" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="8.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0">
                                <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/white" android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/option_a" android:background="@drawable/circle_bg" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="A" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
                                <com.quiz.trivia.helper.CircularProgressIndicator2 android:id="@id/progress_A" android:background="@drawable/aud_progress_bg" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_progress" android:layout_height="@dimen/circle_progress" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" app:direction="clockwise" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/layout_B" android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_progress" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="8.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0">
                                <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/white" android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/option_b" android:background="@drawable/circle_bg" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="B" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
                                <com.quiz.trivia.helper.CircularProgressIndicator2 android:id="@id/progress_B" android:background="@drawable/aud_progress_bg" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_progress" android:layout_height="@dimen/circle_progress" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" app:direction="clockwise" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/layout_C" android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_progress" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="8.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
                                <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/white" android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/option_c" android:background="@drawable/circle_bg" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="C" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
                                <com.quiz.trivia.helper.CircularProgressIndicator2 android:id="@id/progress_C" android:background="@drawable/aud_progress_bg" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_progress" android:layout_height="@dimen/circle_progress" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" app:direction="clockwise" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/layout_D" android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_progress" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="8.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="8.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
                                <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/white" android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/option_d" android:background="@drawable/circle_bg" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="D" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
                                <com.quiz.trivia.helper.CircularProgressIndicator2 android:id="@id/progress_D" android:background="@drawable/aud_progress_bg" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_progress" android:layout_height="@dimen/circle_progress" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" app:direction="clockwise" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout android:gravity="bottom" android:id="@id/bottom_panel" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip" android:weightSum="4.0">
                <ImageView android:id="@id/fifty_fifty" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/left_rigth_margin_score_button" android:src="@drawable/fifty" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                <ImageView android:id="@id/skip_quation" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/left_rigth_margin_score_button" android:src="@drawable/skip" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                <ImageView android:id="@id/audience_poll" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/left_rigth_margin_score_button" android:src="@drawable/audiance" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                <ImageView android:id="@id/reset_timer" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/left_rigth_margin_score_button" android:src="@drawable/timer" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Changed android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" to android:layout_gravity="top|center" but it fixed only the first question. Since then, it's stuck on the scroll position